# How to override default attributes in Chef using roles

Tags: chef-infra

I can't get this to work, been at it for hours. There's a duplicate of this question here, but it was never adequately answered. I've tried to strip the problem down to a minimum.

Here's my trivial recipe: "my_recipe.rb"

```
file "/tmp/my_target_file" do
  content node.default['my_file_content']
  action :create
end
```

...and an attributes file in the attributes subdirectory: "my_attribute.rb"

```
default['my_file_content'] = 'From my_attribute.rb'
```

I create a role in the roles subdirectory: "my_role.rb"

```
name 'my_role'
description 'My role'
run_list 'recipe[my_cookbook::my_recipe]'
default_attributes['my_file_content'] = 'From my_role.rb'
```

I upload both the cookbook and the role to my Chef server and run a knife command from my chef workstation:

```
knife bootstrap xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -x myusername -P mysudopassword --sudo -r role[my_role] -N my_node_name
```

It runs fine and the target file gets created, but the contents of /tmp/my_target_file are not what I expected. I'm getting

```
$ cat /tmp/my_target_file
From my_attribute.rb
```

... but of course what I wanted was

```
$ cat /tmp/my_target_file
From my_role.rb
```

According to Chef attributes precedence, http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html, this should have worked. I've also tried using 'override_attributes' but get the same result. If I login to my Chef server and drill down into the attributes of my node, I can see the attribute

```
my_file_content: From my_role.rb
```

along with the other Ohai generated ones.

There is obviously something I'm not getting here. Can someone please explain how to override attributes using roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file "/tmp/my_target_file" do
  content node.default['my_file_content']
  action :create
end
```

`node.default` is a method call on node object aimed to update the value of `['my_file_content']` attribute in a recipe.

It should not be used to get the value as you're getting the value at the default recipe level (i.e: from attributes files) and not the resulting value from attribute precedence.

Instead use `node['my_file_content']` this way you ask the value of the my_file_content attribute resulting from the different lelvel of precendence.

Use it like this and it will work:

```
file "/tmp/my_target_file" do
  content node['my_file_content']
  action :create
end
```

Comment: It did, thanks. I think I need to know more ruby or no ruby. I have a hard time telling what parts are chef and what parts are ruby.

Comment: The recipe DSL is near ruby, you have learnchef.com and docs.chef.io as starting  reference